# calculate the temperature in a thermal image matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

what I am trying to do is calculate the temperature of a selected area in an image
my code:

```
M=imread('IR003609.BMP');

a = min(M(:));      % find the minimum temperature in the image
b = max(M(:));      % find the maximum temperature in the image

imshow(M,[a b]);    
 h = roipoly();     
  maskOfROI =h;      
  selectedValues = M(maskOfROI);      

averageTemperature =mean(selectedValues)  
maxTemperature = max(selectedValues)       
minTemperature = min(selectedValues)
```

my image is this with the mouth area selected
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQLo5.jpg)

Then the values ​​that he throws at me are these:

```
averageTemperature =

   64.0393


maxTemperature =

  uint8

   255


minTemperature =

  uint8

   1
```

Now my questions are, is the program throwing the correct temperature values ​​(comparing the values ​​seen in the image)? or what values ​​are emissivity?
if they are wrong values ​​how could I solve it?
please help

Comment: These values are not wrong.  I think the problem is that you have the temperature converted to three colors - RGB. You have some zeros for the red and blue layers, and also some 255 here and there.

Comment: And how can I convert RGB colors to temperature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that the color bar is the hue of HSV so I suggest you convert to temperature along these lines: you convert to HSV, use the first layer, then rescale to fit 31-39 deg. And the colors seem to be flipped, so flip them upside down.

```
M = imread('jQLo5.jpg');
Mhsv = rgb2hsv(M);
maxTemp = 39;
minTemp = 31;
Mtemp = (1-Mhsv(:,:,1))*(maxTemp-minTemp)+minTemp;

figure;
imagesc(Mtemp)
colormap(flipud(hsv))
colorbar
```